# one less separator after the last iteration

Tags: pug

Using Jade, I'm trying to display values of an array with a separator (say, a slash `/`)

```
div
  each val in [1, 2, 3]
    span !{val}/
```

But it outputs

> 1/2/3/

appending an unnecessary `/` at the last. I just want

> 1/2/3

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the `length` of your array you can easily use a conditional statement like this:

```
div
  - var arr = [1, 2, 3];
  - var i = 0;
  each val in arr
     - i++;
     span !{val}
         if (i < arr.length)
             | /
```

Maybe a for loop will look a little bit nicer here:

```
div
  - var arr = [1, 2, 3];
  - for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
     span !{arr[i]}
         if (i + 1  < arr.length)
             | /
```

Both will give you this HTML code:

```
<div>
    <span>1/</span>
    <span>2/</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```